# Asymptotics of $\sum_{n\leq x}\tau_{k}\left(n\right)$

Tags: asymptotics, solution-verification, analytic-number-theory

We define $\tau_{k}\left(n\right)$ to be the number of ordered $k$-tuples of positive integers with product equal to $n$. It is easily shown that this satisfies the recurrence relation $\tau_{1}\left(n\right)=1$ and $\tau_{k}\left(n\right)=\sum_{d\mid n}\tau_{k-1}\left(d\right)$, and I would like to show, using $\log^{k}x$ to denote $\left(\log x\right)^{k}$, that $$\sum_{n\leq x}\tau_{k}\left(n\right)=O\left(x\log^{k-1}x\right).$$

The context for this problem essentially is the same as in my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115837/identity-in-number-theory-paper). In the paper by Hu, he uses $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\tau_{k}\left(n\right)}{n}=O\left(\log^{k}x\right)$, citing [this paper by László Tóth](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/40-1/toth.pdf) (PDF file). In that paper, Tóth uses $\sum_{n\leq x}\tau_{k}\left(n\right)=O\left(x\log^{k-1}x\right)$, which he calls a "familiar result". Since it is not so familiar to me, I thought I'd take a shot at proving it.

I proceed by induction. For $k=1$, we have $\sum_{n\leq x}\tau_{1}\left(n\right)=\sum_{n\leq x}1=O\left(x\right).$

Now, suppose that $\sum_{n\leq x}\tau_{k}\left(n\right)=O\left(x\log^{k-1}x\right).$ Then, we have

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\tau_{k+1}\left(n\right)=\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d\mid n}\tau_{k}\left(d\right)=\sum_{ab\leq x}\tau_{k}\left(b\right)=\\ \sum_{a\leq x}\sum_{b\leq x/a}\tau_{k}\left(b\right)=\sum_{a\leq x}O\left(\frac{x}{a}\log^{k-1}\frac{x}{a}\right)=\\ O\left(x\log^{k-1}x\sum_{a\leq x}\frac{1}{a}\right)=O\left(x\log^{k}x\right).\textbf{ QED}(?)$$

Is my attempt at a proof correct? My main issue is the step $\sum_{a\leq x}O\left(\frac{x}{a}\log^{k-1}\frac{x}{a}\right)=O\left(x\log^{k-1}x\sum_{a\leq x}\frac{1}{a}\right)$, as I am unsure if this is allowed. If this turns out to be a faulty step, how would I go about proving this result?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: The step you're worried about is totally fine. You've replaced $\log(x/a)$ with the larger $\log x$, which is valid, and then factored stuff independent of $a$ out of the sum.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you for the verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use partial summation formula:

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d\mid n}\tau_{k}\left(d\right) = \sum_{d \le x} \tau_k(d)\left[\frac{x}{d}\right] = \mathcal{O}\left(x\int_1^x \frac{\log^{k-1} t}{t}\,dt\right) = \mathcal{O}\left(x\log^k x\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer. What is the $\left[\frac{x}{d}\right]$ called and how is it defined?

Comment: @BrianScholl $[x]$ is just the greatest integer not exceeding $x$ (floor function)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'm far too used to using $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ for the floor function.